# Default Page does not open on live server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I am facing a problem of my deployed site that i have set Home Page as Default page when i deployed my site on live server. its work fine on local but on live server when some one tries to open domain name then an error shows but when he enter address concatenated with  home page it works.

you can see my problem on clicking here [online quran reading](http://onlinequranreading.org/Home.aspx)

I think this error in my web.config but if my web.config have errors then why it works with home page?
I am very new to asp.net and deployments etc so please guide me properly.

Comment: Are you hosing on iis server?

Comment: @SenJacob, i have deployed this site on arvixe hosting server.

Comment: I hope you have access to its website control panel. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Setting default document in websitepanel]

You need to set the default document as Home.aspx

Just add `Home.aspx` to the top of default documents list and update.

Read the websitepanel user manual [here](http://www.websitepanel.net/documentation/users-guide/web-sites/#DefaultDocuments)

Comment: i have already set Default.aspx on top of default documents and it redirects to my Home.aspx but i am wonder why this is not working? it is showing web.config file error and i gonna pull out my hairs :(\

Comment: Set custom error to on in web.config and see what is the real issue going on.

Comment: you were right...it was problem in my default document not redirected to home.aspx.now i have solved it out.